# форма с иконкой

Tags: css

Здравствуйте! 
Необходимо разместить иконку внутри формы справа.
Иконка не отображается. В чем проблема?

Пример как должно быть.

[image: Вот пример как должно быть]

Мой код:

CSS

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
header{
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #828282;
}
.navigation{
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #24252d;
    height: 3em;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
/*.box {
    display: block;
}*/
.social_networks {
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
}

.box {
    float: right;
    padding: 18px;
}
.container-1{
  width: 300px;
  vertical-align: right;
}
.container-1 input#search{
  width: 200px;
  height: 28px;
  background: #000000;
  border: none;
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: #63717f;
  padding-left: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}


input {
    background-image: url('search.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: 0px center;
    padding-left: 18px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /
</head>
<body>
  <div class="all">
    <header>
    <div class="navigation">
       <div class="box">
             <div class="container-1">
             <form>
               <!-- <span class="icon"><img src="search.png"></span> -->
               <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search"/>
             </form>
             </div> <!--container-->
          </div> <!--box-->
           <div class="social_networks">
            <img src="twitter.png">
            <img src="facebook.png">
            <img src="dribble.png">
            <img src="lastfm.png">
            <img src="linkedin.png">
            <img src="tumblr.png">
           </div><!--social_networks-->
        </div><!--navigation-->
     </div> <!--all-->
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: у вас нету закрывающей скобки вот тут `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />`

Answer (score 2):

Так проверяй firebug-ом (в хроме <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) и ищи, какой атрибут стиля делает не то, что ты хочешь. И вообще, я не вижу описания класса icon или img...
P.S. Надеюсь, в реальном коде span с иконкой не закомментирован?))

Comment: f12 быстрее будет )

Answer (score 1):

Немножко изменил css код:

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #828282;
}
.navigation {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #24252d;
    height: 3em;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.box {
    float: right;
    padding: 18px;
}
.container-1 {
    width: 300px;
    vertical-align: right;
}
#search {
    width: 200px;
    height: 28px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #63717f;
    padding-left: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(search.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
    <header>
    <div class="navigation">
       <div class="box">
             <div class="container-1">
             <form>
               <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search"/>
             </form>
             </div> <!--container-->
          </div> <!--box-->
        </div><!--navigation-->
    </header>
</div> <!--all-->
```